# making submit button execute a function

Tags: javascript

Basicly i have this function:

```
function testLength(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value

    alert("test")
    if (input1.length < 2 && input2.lenght < 2){
        alert("Please enter more then one symbol");
        return false
    }
}
```

and a intputs:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input1">
<input type="submit" onclick="testLength();" value="press me">
```

the idea is if the inputs are 1 character long, not allow the submission but although even if my inputs are 1 character long, it doesn't appear to go into the if statment which (I assume) should stop submit button from submitting. Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at things like `<form onsubmit="return testLength()">`.

The function will not be submitted if the function return false.

Comment: Ok, so I managed to stop submit button from doing its thing. I still cant make it go thro the if statement, for some reason it returns false (the condition) no matter what i enter :S

Comment: What code are you using ? There's a typo in the code in your question : lenght instead of length

Comment: \*facepalm* So it just cames down to me not being able to spell properly. It works just fine now. Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Use the onsubmit event:

```
<form onsubmit="return testLength();">
    <input type="text" name="input1">
    <input type="text" name="input2">
    <input type="submit" value="press me">
</form>
```

For more info, read: [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your inputs and submit button are inside a `<form>` element, the form's default behavior (which is to actually be submitted) is what's going to happen. What you might want to do is add an event listener for the form's `submit` event, and do your validations in there.

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" name="input1">
    <input type="text" name="input2">
    <input type="submit" value="press me">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var form = document.getElementById('my-form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value

    alert("test")
    if (input1.length < 2 && input2.lenght < 2){
        alert("Please enter more then one symbol");
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from onsubmit, you can also use the eventListener.

eg :

```
document.querySelector('').addEventListener('click', testLength);
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" name="input1">
    <input type="text" name="input2">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="press me">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', testLength);
    function testLength(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value

    alert("test")
    if (input1.length < 2 && input2.lenght < 2){
        alert("Please enter more then one symbol");
        return false
    }
}
```

The event listener can be use not only with querySelector and getelementByID, but with any target you defined see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the Documentation.